# site resurrected looks like clone therefore no google ranking (i think) used to be page 1

Tags: seo, ranking

It's late please don't shoot me for lack of research on this one but SEO is a whole field of it's own and I have no idea where to start.

I have a site (fightingfantasy.net) that used to be fightingfantasy.org - I lost the domain name several years ago due to hospitalisation to speculators (last I knew they wanted in excess of £500 for it and I survive on welfare) ) so I rebranded as the .net

I used to rank page 1 on google for the term 'fighting fantasy' (and very well for 'gamebooks' and so on). Now I rank nowhere at all - I mean nowhere. I took the advantage to develop my site somewhat (it is largely a labour of love and generates no money), for a numberof years however the utter lack of search related traffic has become crushingly depressing.

The only explanation I can think of is that Google reckons I am a clone. If anyone at all has any idea what I can do... please help... StackExchange you are my only hope...

(originally posted on StackOverflow in ignorance :-/ )

Comment: It appears that the domain `fightingfantasy.org` is currently suspended by Namecheap due to not being able to verify the owner's contact info. I'd give the sales department there a call and explain the situation - if they can't verify the information, perhaps they'll delete the domain and you can backorder it with them. In regards to Google, if the site can't be reached, you're not a clone of it. In fact, only the root domain is indexed (use `site:fightingfantasy.org` in Google to view what's indexed). It seems like you'll need to rebuild your SEO from scratch either way...

Comment: I'm afraid it's just too broadly-scoped a question for us to tell you how to do that, but the linked question may help. Good luck!

Comment: thank you Dan that's extremely useful :-)  I'm sorry I couldn't scope the question any tighter just as I say SEO etc. is something I know nothing of.